# Move polygon to new location (find new lat-lng coordinates)

Tags: coordinate-system, polygon, coordinates, latitude-longitude, geolocation

I need to move my polygon (region of geographical area) with 4 different (**O1, O2, O3 and O4**) lat-lng coordinates (as shown in the figure) to another place, so that I get new values of all 4 lat-lng coordinates (**N1, N2, N3 and N4**).

[image]

So if I have one lat-lng for example the **N1**, how can I calculate other three coordinates (**N2, N3 and N4**)?

I am using Parallelogram formula to find the new coordinates.
For example, if I need to calculate **N2** coordinate, I will use Points **O1, O2 and N1** as the three coordinates of a parallelogram and use them to calculate **N2** coordinate.

But is that a correct way to calculate all coordinates? I feel this could work properly for a XY coordinate system but is it valid for lat-lng coordinates system as well?

Comment: A *move* is just a shift of the coordinates. If you know the deltaX and deltaY, you just need to add them to all vertices. Constructing a parallelogram seems like wasted effort. Note that shifting an object in decimal degrees changes its size.